# Building a custom search module for Magento adhering to Search Type configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, products, catalogsearch, search

I´m in the middle of building a search module for Magento, and I´m currently facing a little bit of trouble, specifically regarding applying "Search Types" (Like, Fulltext or Combine) according to the admin configuration.

Here is my working query code:

```
$searchQuery = 'my search';
$storeId = '1';
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel("catalog/product_collection")->addAttributeToSelect("*");
$query = Mage::helper("catalogSearch")->getQuery();
$query->setStoreId($storeId);
$query->setQueryText($searchQuery);
$collection = $query->getSearchCollection();
$collection->addSearchFilter($searchQuery);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect("*");
$collection->addCategoryIds();
$collection->addFinalPrice();
$collection->addUrlRewrite();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$collection->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$collection->setPageSize(20);
```

The only thing I need is to somehow define "Search Types" so it´s either "like", "fulltext" or "combine" depending on the shop configuration.

In other words, if the shop owner has set "Search Type" to "Combine(Like and Fulltext)" - then my query must also be search type "combine".

My problem is that I don´t know where to apply search type in the query.

I hope someone out there can help.

P.S. I normally work in Joomla, so I´m a complete novice when it comes to the Magento framework..

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the correct solution.
It turned out I was using the wrong approach regarding the query.

I managed to modify my query according to Ron´s answer to this thread: [What's the proper way to call CatalogSearch from a custom Block in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978893/whats-the-proper-way-to-call-catalogsearch-from-a-custom-block-in-magento)

Here is my final query, which performs a search according to the general Magento catalog search settings in admin:

```
$searchQuery = 'my search';
$shopidajax = '1';

$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($shopidajax);

$searchText = $searchQuery;
$query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($searchText)->prepare();
$fulltextResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->prepareResult(
    Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext'), 
    $searchText, 
    $query
);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->getSelect()->joinInner(
    array('search_result' => $collection->getTable('catalogsearch/result')),
    $collection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
        'search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id=?',
        $query->getId()
    ),
    array('relevance' => 'relevance')
);

$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

$collection->setStore($storeId);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addMinimalPrice();
$collection->addFinalPrice();
$collection->addTaxPercents();
$collection->addStoreFilter();
$collection->addUrlRewrite();
$collection->addCategoryIds();
$collection->setPageSize(20);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Note that $shopidajax should be the current active shop ID and $searchQuery should of course be the actual search query string.

Answer (score 0):

In my case results are different from native search and from above methods
I used filters like in layers (app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer.php F:prepareProductCollection) and also add following filter for same results as on web:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order('relevance DESC');
```